# function not being found in secret_token.rb trying to update RoR from 3.2 to 4.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hello I am trying to update my rails web app from rails 3.2 to rails 4.0. I am having some issues with my secret key creater/reader function not being seen by the rails server on start up.

secret_key.rb  3.2 file

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.
# Your secret key for verifying the integrity of signed cookies.
# If you change this key, all old signed cookies will become invalid!
# Make sure the secret is at least 30 characters and all random,
# no regular words or you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
MiningApp::Application.config.secret_token = 'key-is-here'
```

secret_key.rb 4.0 file

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.
# Your secret key for verifying the integrity of signed cookies.
# If you change this key, all old signed cookies will become invalid!
# Make sure the secret is at least 30 characters and all random,
# no regular words or you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.

require 'securerandom'

def secure_token
 token_file = Rails.root.join('.secret')
 if File.exist?(token_file)
   # Use the existing token.
    File.read(token_file).chomp
 else
    # Generate a new token and store it in token_file.
     token = SecureRandom.hex(64)
     File.write(token_file, token)
     token
 end
end

MiningApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = secure_token
```

When I start my rails server it says that

```
secret_token.rb:12 in `secure_token': undefined method `exist' for File:class (NoMethodError)
```

Basically it cannot find that function defined above the line. Not sure why it isn't finding it.

Comment: which is line 12? why is the error `exist` when your code says `exist?`?

Comment: line 12 is `MiningApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = secure_token`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23124480/config-initializers-secret-token-rb-not-being-generated-why-not), secret_token.rb has been replaced in Rails 4 with **secrets.yml**.  Also, note that it's located differently as well.

Comment: This looks like it was this was my issue. Will update