# /config/initializers/secret_token.rb not being generated. Why not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently going through a rails tutorial and I need to make some modifications to `/config/initializers/secret_token.rb`, however, I can't find this file anywhere within the `initializers` directory. I am running the latest version of rails. This is the line I used in the terminal to create a rails project:

```
rails new sample_app
```

Anyone know why it isn't showing up?

Comment: Hey Byron, were you able to find a solution around this?  I'm following the same tutorial and got stuck at this point.  I'm wondering if copy&paste to secreats.yml (instead of secret_token.rb) would do it.

Comment: I experimented to no avail. I decided to just skip any of the "testing" material and to study it separately at a later time.

Comment: Thanks. I did the same thing.  Oh and btw, copying & pasting the code to secrets.yml will not work.

Comment: See my answer below. The short version is you need to install the exact version of Rails used in the tutorial. Rails 4.1 and Rails 4.0 differ in this small respect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The tutorial you're looking at was likely written for an older version of Rails than you're using.

`secret_token.rb` existed in Rails 3 and Rails 4.0 apps; it does not exist in Rails 4.1 apps.

It has been replaced in Rails 4.1 by the **secrets.yml** file:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#config-secrets-yml

Comment: thanks for pointing that out!  I'm following the same tutorial by Hartl.  Do you know if we just copy and paste the same code to secrets.yaml instead of secret_token.rb?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not quite right: It's Rails 4.1, not Rails 4 per se, that has changed over from secret_token.rb to secrets.yml.

Answer (score 17):

Thanks for pointing this out. The issue is probably due to using Rails 4.1 instead of Rails 4.0 as specified in the *Rails Tutorial*. It's because of issues like this that [Section 1.2.2](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-rubygems) states (bold in original)

> **Unless otherwise noted, you should use the exact versions of all software used in the tutorial, including Rails itself, if you want the same results.**

To get things to work, first uninstall the current version of Rails:

```
$ gem uninstall rails railties
```

Then follow the instructions [exactly as written in the tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-install_rails) to install Rails 4.0:

```
$ gem install rails --version 4.0.4
```

Generating a test app (skipping Bundler for convenience) and piping the output through `grep` then verifies that `secret_token.rb` gets generated:

```
$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.4
$ rails new test_app --skip-bundle | grep secret_token
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
```

At this point, you should be able to follow the rest of the tutorial as written.

By the way, I'm about to start work on a 3rd edition of the tutorial, and will plan to take care of this issue as part of a more general update.

Comment: Thanks for the post!  If I may ask, when is the target released date of the 3rd edition?

Comment: I've learned from experience never to make precise estimates, but I hope to have something to show sometime this summer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using 4.1.1. Dont copy nothing to the secrets.yml, just dont forget to update the gitignore file (http://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#code-gitignore)

With this you can keep going on the tutorial

Comment: Update the gitignore file to what? What should i replace? If you're new to all this you really have no idea about this stuff.