# Do I need both devise and rails secret keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Inside `config/initializers` there is `secret_token.rb` and `devise.rb`, both of which have a slot to enter a secret key. For devise its `config.secret_key` and for rails it is `Application.config.secret_key_base`.

Do I need both of these things to be set? I don't understand which secret keys control which behaviors.

Comment: I don't find any `secret_token.rb`. Which version of Rails you are using?

Comment: @Pavan: according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23124507/347165) that file is used for rails 3 and 4 and was deprecated for 4.1. But I have the analogous question for `secrets.yml`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I struggled with this at first too. It's not really that clearly explained in the docs.

#### Devise usage of Secret Key

From the Devise [repository](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a/lib/devise/rails.rb#L34):

```
initializer "devise.secret_key" do |app|
  if app.respond_to?(:secrets)
    Devise.secret_key ||= app.secrets.secret_key_base
  elsif app.config.respond_to?(:secret_key_base)
    Devise.secret_key ||= app.config.secret_key_base
  end

  Devise.token_generator ||=
    if secret_key = Devise.secret_key
      Devise::TokenGenerator.new(
        ActiveSupport::CachingKeyGenerator.new(ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new(secret_key))
      )
    end
end
```

From the code above, once `Devise.secret_key` is assigned a value, it is then used to generate a token, which is also used for several Devise functionalities such as account confirmation, resetting passwords and unlocking accounts. All of these require a token, and that token by the code shown above.

Then from the configuration file `devise.rb`:

```
# The secret key used by Devise. Devise uses this key to generate
# random tokens. Changing this key will render invalid all existing
# confirmation, reset password and unlock tokens in the database.
# Devise will use the `secret_key_base` as its `secret_key`
# by default. You can change it below and use your own secret key.
```

This means **you *don't need* to set or create a separate `secret_key` for Devise to work**. If you already have a `secret_key_base` set, as explained in the comments above, then Devise's `secret_key' will just default to that.

I personally just commented out the code, but you're free to even delete the line that assigns `config.secret_key`.

#### Rails usage of Secret Key

`secret_key_base` is used for signing and encrypting cookies, and it's very well explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467012/what-is-the-difference-between-signed-and-encrypted-cookies-in-rails).